# How do I tell Lilypond to start hymns on new page

Tags: lilypond

I'm typesetting a hymn. For this particular project, it has the following requirements

- Every hymn must start on a new page. (Not strethced/spaced out, short hymn scores to sit at the top normally).
- If the hymn overflows to the following page (1 or 2 line of music), leave that line of music sits at the top of the page, and start a new hymn on a new page.
- Cannot have 2 short hymns on 1 page.

How should I tell Lilypond to do this?

When I tried placing manual `\pageBreak` as such;

```
% Include songs from here ----------------------------------------------------------
\include "psalm1.ly"
\pageBreak

\include "psalm2.ly"
\pageBreak

\include "psalm3.ly"
\pageBreak
```

This gives me the following. Too spaced out.

[image]

For The second hymn, it has an overflow 1 music line. But it became too spaced out too! The requirement is to condense the score and leave the hanging 1 extra line music there, and start on a new page.

[image]

I feel `\pageBreak` is not what I am looking for here.

Can someone help me with my typesetting requirements?

Comment: If you want to keep the systems near the top of the page and not stretched over the page, you can add `\paper { ragged-bottom = ##t }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want stretching at all setting the variable

```
\paper {
  ragged-bottom = ##t
}
```

would do the trick. Else you can use `\bookpart { ... }` for this.

Comment: Thanks. `ragged-bottom = ##t` was exactly what I needed. This works well. As for `\bookPart`, I haven't figured out know how to use it yet. I tried `\bookPart { \include "psalm1.ly"}`, and whole psalm 1 dissapeared from the final output.